# os.system('clear') printing white space

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm coding a console-based program. I use os.system('clear') a lot, and this causes a white space to be written in the first position in the screen (top left character in the console).

The problem I'm having is that this happens more or less randomly and I have not been able to figure out a pattern so I can fix it.

I have tried replicating it with basic things like this:

```
while 1:
  os.system('clear')
  print "######################"
  print "######################"
  raw_input()
```

but without luck. In my program, however, it hapens quite a lot. So I take it only happens when I do something before or after clearing, but there is no constant and it can happen at any moment (After a certain action you may or may not get this when trying multiple times).

Has anyone encountered this behaviour? Does anyone know what causes this? There is nothing on the python documentation and I haven't been able to find the cause nor the remedy by looking online.

Just in case [here is the code](https://github.com/Achifaifa/kirino/tree/master/source), although I don't expect anyone to actually read it. As I said it happens more or less randomly, so I can't tell which instruction, function or module is the problem in it. It has been happening since people first started testing it (Code was only a few hundred lines back then), so it take it's a very basic combination of clear and write/input instructions.

Any cluse about what could be causing this will be appreciated.

Comment: Try sys.stdout.flush() before the clear, maybe there is something in the pipe. And you could try to clear via the curses module instead of calling out.

Comment: @wnnmaw I'm using debian 7.something. tdelaney, I'm not using curses. I'll try the flush and see what happens

Comment: @tdelaney Replaced all the clear instructions with flush and clear, it still happens.

Comment: flush after clear, to be sure that the buffer is sended to console

Comment: Sorry I forgot to reply but no, that does not work either. I'm thinking maybe it has to do with the code I use to read characters from screen https://github.com/joeyespo/py-getch

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using:

```
subprocess.call('clear')
```

I typically put this in a separate function like 'clr_screen()' and then call it as needed.